# Suggest community wiki based on title keywords, tags

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

My suggestion is that when someone is asking a question, certain conditions cause a message to appear advising the user that their question may be appropriate for community wiki status, and explaining briefly what this means.  The conditions under which this would happen would include:

1. The title containing any of the keywords:

   - favorite
   - opinion
   - most
   - least
   - best (or possibly phrase "are the best")
   - worst
   - think
   - feel
2. Any of these tags are used:

   - fun
   - subjective
   - not-programming-related (for SO)
   - poll
   - off-topic
   - humor

Comment: a form of this already exists. Go to the /ask page and try entering some of these keywords in the title, then press tab.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for what is Community Wiki are so screwed up already I don't know if you could effectively program to look for questions that might be CW status.

I think before we try and provide helpful tips to question askers, we need to figure out what CW actually means first.

It should also be noted that they could easily avoid the little warning by  just not using those tags as well.

Answer (score 3):

I like this suggestion, but would also like to see them start out closed and require five votes to re-open...

Comment: You're a damned dirty fascist.

Comment: Pony-loving hippie!

Comment: MALE LOVE NOT WAR!

Comment: Uh...nice typo?

Comment: ... Well his image is of a Pony.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just start everything as CW and require 5 votes to turn it into a regular question.  I'm only half-kidding.

Comment: I actually think it should take 25 votes.